# Connecting to Remote MySQL DB in docker container using PDO

Tags: mysql, docker, pdo

I am a bit of a newbie and new to the php coding world and have a small task I am trying to find an answer to, but I cannot seem to find the relevant question asked anywhere before.

Basically I have a server where I create reports from mySQL DBs located on other remote machines.

So far these other servers have had a basic mysql server running on them and I can easily connect to them with PDO like this:

```
$DBcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
$DBcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

But I now have a server running mySQL inside of a docker container on this remote server.

So my question is, is it possible to connect to this mySQL db as well using PDO?

I am able to connect to the DB remotely with mySQL workbench using  Standard TCP/IP over SSH (as I also do with the other servers), but the one thing I have to specify differently here compared to the other servers not using docker is the 'MySQL server host relative to the SSH server'. Usually just having 127.0.0.1 here is fine, but with mySQL inside a docker container I first have to find this relative address with

`docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' database-name`

you then get something like 172.21.0.5 and add this in that field

[workbench connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4p7U.png)

How are you able to represent this small change in the PDO statement? Is it still possible to connect in this way?

Answer (score 0):

actually, no. You can't connect inside code as mysql workbench over ssh. But you can use ssh jumb for this connection as below link.
https://www.tecmint.com/access-linux-server-using-a-jump-host/

You should configure jump command to a mysql servers with port. this jump command provides your connection via bastion you mentioned instance for ssh to the mysql server.

for example: ssh -N  -i pemfile.pem(if you have to connect to jump server) -L fakemysqlserverip:3306:mysqlserverrealip:3306 ec2-user@jumpserverip
fakemysqlserverip may be localhost,127.0.0.1 or different
jumpserverip is your server which is for using over ssh

Regards